# Bootstrap 4 Datatables search by return value

Tags: php, datatable, datatables, bootstrap-4

I have a table wherein I have a status field which has values as 0 and 1 in database which indicates "Pending" and "Approved" resp.
I am trying to search using bootstrap 4 datatables which is working fine for rest all fields except the status field. The issue is that my display value is "Pending" and "Approved" which does not match the database value of 0 and 1. 
So if I search by pending or approved then it returns "no results" . However if i search with 0 or 1 I get proper results.

Can anyone advise as to how I should change the code so as to allow searching with my display values of pending and approved?

Please find screenshots and codes.

### **JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "aoColumnDefs" : [{"bSearchable":false, "aTargets":[3]}],
        "ajax": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "prison/bootstrap_datatable",
    });
});
```

### **Code**

```
public function bootstrap_datatable_view() { 
    $data['title'] = "bootstrap datatable";
    $this->load->view('templates/admin/header', $data);

?>
<div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Prison Name</th>
            <th>Prison Address</th>
            <th>Prison Country</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>    
            <th>Prison Name</th>
            <th>Prison Address</th>
            <th>Prison Country</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table></div>
<?php $this->load->view('templates/admin/footer');
}
public function bootstrap_datatable() {
    $this->load->library('ssp');

    $table = $this->db->dbprefix('prison');

    // Table's primary key
    $primaryKey = 'id';

    // Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
    // The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
    // parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
    // indexes
    $columns = array(
        array( 'db' => 'prison_name', 'dt' => 0 ),
        array( 'db' => 'prison_address', 'dt' => 1 ),
        array( 'db' => 'prison_country', 'dt' => 2 ),
        array(
            'db' => 'status',
            'dt' => 3,
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                if ($d == 1) {
                    return "Approved";
                } else {
                    return "Pending";
                }
            }
        ),
        array(
            'db' => 'id',
            'dt' => 4,
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                return "<a class='btn btn-warning' href='edit/$d'>Edit</a>";
            }
        ),
        array(
            'db' => 'id',
            'dt' => 5,
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                return "<a class='btn btn-danger' href='delete/$d'>Delete</a>";

            }
        )
    );

    // SQL server connection information
    $sql_details = array(
        'user' => $this->db->username,
        'pass' => $this->db->password,
        'db' => $this->db->database,
        'host' => $this->db->hostname
    );

    echo json_encode(
        SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
    );
}
```

[image: No results Found]
[image: All data]

Comment: cant you search with keyword Approved directly??

Comment: No because the datatables search from database values directly and in the database the value is 1 in place of approved. So if I search by 1 then the correct results appear.

Comment: You can use buttons to filter those with status

Comment: another way is that modify your query like if status is 1 then take approved 0 then take not approved

Comment: can you specify more about using buttons ? I am not clear..

Comment: Also for modifying query, I have already mentioned in my question that the the sorting is done with bootstrap 4 datatables so we just have to specify the database field and it generates the query automatically. We need an option to modify the query which is used by datatables.

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()#Example

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/